# jQuery issues in iphone

Tags: jquery, iphone

I have used the jQuery effects to auto fill the text filed. In all the browsers it is working fine. Even in the andriod phone it is working fine. But it is not working fine in Iphone.

This is my markup and code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#tostreet").blur(function(){
var  street=$("#tostreet").val();
if(street=='schiphol'){
$("#tostreet").val('Vertrekpassage');
$("#tohouse").val('1');
$("#tocity").val('SCHIPHOL');

    }
  });
});

<input class="text_field" id="tostreet" onkeyup="repp();" type="text" name="tostreet" placeholder="Street" />
<input class="short_text_field" id="tohouse" type="text" name="tohouse" placeholder="No." value="" />

</div>
</div>
<div class="field_box">
<div class="input_text"><label></label></div>
<div class="field"><input class="full_text_field" id="tocity" type="text" name="tocity" placeholder="City" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to specify what "not working fine" actually means. Are there errors? Does nothing happen? Does the phone crash?

Comment: no nothing happened. It is working fine on all browsers except in iphone. On andriod it is working fine. When someone fills " schiphol " on <input class="text_field" id="tostreet" onkeyup="repp();" type="text" name="tostreet" placeholder="Street" /> and go to another filed then it should automatically fill <input class="text_field" id="tostreet" onkeyup="repp();" type="text" name="tostreet" placeholder="Street" /> with Vertrekpassage. this is working fine on andriod and aon firefox,chrome safari. But on IPhone it is not working